# SIGSEGV 0xb on Java 1.6 and 1.7 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, node.js, ubuntu, jvm, segmentation-fault

I have really annoying problems with Java 1.6 and Java 1.7 on Ubuntu 13.10 (and Xubuntu 12.10), both x64. My problem doesn't occur on Debian 6.0 x64.

I run some test code for a nodejs application running Java code per JNI (if I understand it correctly, I'm not the developer of the code). The developers said, that it worked with no problems on their systems.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0aef63e2fb, pid=3442, tid=139685052057408
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5842fb]  JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg::JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg(_jmethodID*, __va_list_tag*)+0x1b
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Full log is on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bexYiHHJ

I am using VMWare Workstation 9.0.2 to virtualize Ubuntu 13.10 x64, Xubuntu 12.10 x64 and Debian 6.0. I get the same error with Java 1.6. I also tried the OPENJDK Java. It works completly fine under Debian 6.0 with kernel 2.8 but doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.10 and Xubuntu (here are kernels 3.5 and 3.8, but should this really matter?).

What can I do now? I searched a lot in the internet and this board here. Sometimes it was defected hardware but I virtualize here and it works on Debian. Some others said to add some parameters but I don't really know where to add these parameters because I don't run Java from the command line, it will automatically started in the Node.JS Application.

Please Help!

Comment: I actually mean Ubuntu 13.04, not 13.10 ;).

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem and it was solved with this java parameter: -XX:-UseCompressedOops

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was, but I switched to a Debian 7 Version with Kernel 3.2 as work system. First, I had the same problem but then I installed a basic installation and download the precompiled node.js application. Maybe in my GCC was something wrong, I don't know.

If someone had the same problem and got a solution, it would be nice to know what the cause was.